# Replace strings with longest string in group

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Consider this dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Dirk Nowitzki", "Dirk Nowitzki", "LeBron James", "Lebron James", "Kobe Bryant", "Kobe Bryant"),
                 team = c("Mavericks", "Mavs", "Cavs", "Cavaliers", "Lakers", "Lakers"))
           name      team
1 Dirk Nowitzki Mavericks
2 Dirk Nowitzki      Mavs
3  LeBron James      Cavs
4  Lebron James Cavaliers
5   Kobe Bryant    Lakers
6   Kobe Bryant    Lakers
```

I'd like to replace the shortened team names with their longer counterparts and get this

```
           name      team
1 Dirk Nowitzki Mavericks
2 Dirk Nowitzki Mavericks
3  LeBron James Cavaliers
4  Lebron James Cavaliers
5   Kobe Bryant    Lakers
6   Kobe Bryant    Lakers
```

It's easy enough to use `gsub` or `str_replace` to do this one by one in a toy example, but the actual dataset has thousands of incomplete strings.

I can group by name, and determine which team name is longest, but then I get stuck

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(str_len = str_length(team))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the 'name's differ by case, so it is better to change it to a common case while grouping, and then get the index of max length with `which.max` and replace the 'team' with that corresponding value for 'team'

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(name2 = toupper(name)) %>% 
   mutate(team = team[which.max(str_length(team))]) %>%
   ungroup  %>%
   select(-name2)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  name          team     
#  <fct>         <fct>    
#1 Dirk Nowitzki Mavericks
#2 Dirk Nowitzki Mavericks
#3 LeBron James  Cavaliers
#4 Lebron James  Cavaliers
#5 Kobe Bryant   Lakers   
#6 Kobe Bryant   Lakers
```

Comment: This for sure will work, assuming one player only has one team. I know that isn't true for most players.  With that said, this is exactly what was asked for.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I asked for, so I'll accept when the timer expires.  The example is just that, an example.  My real dataset doesn't involve NBA players, so trades or free agency aren't a factor.

Comment: Lebron James has played for several teams: Heat, Cavaliers, Lakers.  If that was actually contained within the data, grouping by name and then using the max length team value would make every record 'Cavaliers'.  (Greg's comment above suggest this isn't an issue)

Comment: @TTS I agree that  it would be a case, but we can could then have the 'team'  also as a group  variable by creating another group with `stringdist`.  Wouldn't that work then

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(team_full = case_when(
     team == 'Cavs' ~ 'Cavaliers',
     team == 'Mavs' ~ 'Mavericks',
     TRUE ~ team))
```

*Note the lists can be more inclusive for multiple values like...

```
team %in% c('Mavs', 'mavs', 'Mavrix') ~ 'Mavericks,
```

Comment: This is nice, but it does still require manually entering in all the possible shortened strings, which is what I was trying to get away from when I said I'd prefer not to manually use ```str_replace```, ```gsub``` etc.